# Measure execution time in Project Reactor

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I'm trying to load test one of my projects and I think somewhere in my changes I may have introduced some point where the performance is getting impacted.

Is there a way to measure **execution time** and **log** in case it exceeds the threshold?

```
flux
  .<doOnSomethingIsTakingTooLong>(signal -> 
       log.error("SLOW PROCESSING {}", signal), Duration.ofSeconds(2)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve it:

1. **Expose metrics**

It's not exactly what you asked, but metrics would be a preferred way to collect such information. Reactor exposes multiple metrics that could help to investigate performance issues. You could use `metrics()` operator in conjunction with `name()` & `tag()` to emit metrics. For more details, see [Exposing Reactor metrics](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#metrics)

```
events()
    .flatMap(rec ->
            processEvent(rec)
              .name("process") 
              .metrics() 
    )
```

You could also enable scheduler metrics `Schedulers.enableMetrics();`

This project has a good example of monitoring based on Prometheus and Grafana [Reactor monitoring demo](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-monitoring-demo).

2. **Use context to measure execution time**

The idea is to save start time in the context and then calculate execution time when complete event is emitted.

```
events()
    .flatMap(rec ->
            processEvent(rec)
                 .transform(this::reportExecutionTime)
    );
```

where `reportExecutionTime` is implemented like the following

```
private <T> Mono<T> reportExecutionTime(Mono<T> mono) {
    String taskStartMsKey = "task.start";

    return Mono.deferContextual(ctx -> mono
                    .doOnSuccess(__ -> {
                        var executionTime = currentTimeMillis() - ctx.<Long>get(taskStartMsKey);
                        log.info("execution time: {}", executionTime);
                    })
            )
            .contextWrite(ctx -> ctx.put(taskStartMsKey, currentTimeMillis()));
}
```

Here is a full test example

```
@Test
void reportExecutionTimeTest() {
    var stream = events()
            .flatMap(rec ->
                    processEvent(rec)
                            .transform(this::reportExecutionTime)
            );

    StepVerifier.create(stream)
            .expectNextCount(100)
            .verifyComplete();
}

private <T> Mono<T> reportExecutionTime(Mono<T> mono) {
    String taskStartMsKey = "task.start";

    return Mono.deferContextual(ctx -> mono
                    .doOnSuccess(__ -> {
                        var executionTime = currentTimeMillis() - ctx.<Long>get(taskStartMsKey);
                        log.info("execution time: {}", executionTime);
                    })
            )
            .contextWrite(ctx -> ctx.put(taskStartMsKey, currentTimeMillis()));
}

private Flux<Integer> events() {
    return Flux.range(1, 100);
}

private Mono<Integer> processEvent(int i) {
    return Mono.delay(Duration.ofMillis(i + 100))
            .thenReturn(i);
}
```

Comment: thanks this helps a bit.  Worried me for a moment thinking why did it take 100+ ms to process each entry till I saw the mono.delay.

Comment: One suggestion. Use .doFinally() instead of doOnSuccess() to measure time. Usually you want to monitor and watch avg processing time and doOnSuccess() excludes error states.

Comment: `doFinally`was deprecated and  removed in 3.4.0. To measure latency for a error requests you can use `doOnError but it’s also important to distinguish between failed and successful requests, as failed ones might take sensibly less time than the correct ones. Better to add another label to be able to measure both scenarios.